# Tkinter проблема с обработчиком ошибок

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, tkinter, gui

Суть проблемы такова.
Имеется функция. Которая опрашивает прибор каждую секунду и выводит результат опроса на экран. Для соединения используется VISA и Py-Visa.

Если происходит обрыв соединения, то на экран должно выводиться, что произошла ошибка соединения. И при восстановлении соединения. Снятие показаний должно продолжаться. Однако, после разрыва, сначала программа фризится и потом уже вылезает, что "соединение прервано", но при возобновлении не происходит ничего.

Не знаю правильно ли я организовал много поточность и обработчик ошибок. Нужен совет, как это исправить

```py
    def meas(self):
        self.mesframe = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe, padding='5 5 10 10').grid(column=0, row=8)
        self.mesheader = Label(self.mesframe, text='Измерения', font=10).grid(column=1, row=8, columnspan=2,
                                                                              pady=5, stick=W)
        self.instpow = Label(self.mesframe, text='Уровень на входе приемника:').grid(column=1, row=9, columnspan=2,
                                                                                     pady=5, stick=W)
        self.instpownum = Label(self.mesframe, text='0')
        self.instpownum.grid(column=3, row=9, columnspan=2, pady=5, stick=W)
        self.startb = Button(self.mesframe, text='Начать',
                             command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=self.startMeas).start())
        self.startb.grid(column=1, row=10, pady=5, stick=W)

    def startMeas(self):
        try:
            self.fm_pow = scope.query_ascii_values('CALC:MARK:FUNC:POW:RES? CPOW')
            self.instpownum.configure(text='%s' % self.fm_pow, fg='green')
        except pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError:
            self.instpownum.configure(text='Проверьте соединение', fg='red')
        self.after(1000, self.startMeas)
```